# Should my GCM server always be running for successful device registration?

Tags: android, exception, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing a GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) client-server. I always get error `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`. I studied all posts about this error but I could not solve it.

Only remained reason for this error is server. I have not implemented the server yet. Can it be the reason of getting `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error?

Comment: Check your network proxy.. make sure ports 80,443 and 5223 are not blocked... in other words the same ports for google chat

Comment: @PankajKumar Should My GCM server always be running?

Comment: what do you mean by your GCM server?

Comment: @PankajKumar gcm-server that sends my messages to Android devices.

Comment: when you need to send msg from server then that should be run.. but the error is not from your server. this is from google GCM server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what docs say in regards to `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error:

> When the application receives a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent with the error
>   extra set as SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, it should retry the failed
>   operation (register or unregister).
>
> In the simplest case, if your application just calls register and GCM
>   is not a fundamental part of the application, the application could
>   simply ignore the error and try to register again the next time it
>   starts. Otherwise, it should retry the previous operation using
>   exponential back-off. In exponential back-off, each time there is a
>   failure, it should wait twice the previous amount of time before
>   trying again.

So the answer is no, this error is not caused because you did not implemented the server yet, but rather because the registration on GCM server failed.

(Only after the registration on GCM server was successful and you received a registration id, you would send that registration id to your application server.)